# DataTable How to add row with attributes Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using [**Datatable**](https://datatables.net/) plugin in table. I am adding row dynamically by Jquery:

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
 t.row.add( [
    counter +'.1',
    counter +'.2',
    counter +'.3',
    counter +'.4',
    counter +'.5'
] ).draw();
```

Here is fiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7w0w9ob6/). But i haven't found anything how can i add attributes on `<tr>`?

As per my need i want to add `data-id`,`class`,`id` and any other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem:

```
var data = [
    counter +'.1',
    counter +'.2',
    counter +'.3',
    counter +'.4',
    counter +'.5'
];
var rowIndex = t.fnAddData(data);
var row = t.fnGetNodes(rowIndex);
$(row).attr( 'id', 'MyUniqueID' );
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7w0w9ob6/8/) and [**Details**](https://datatables.net/api)